# Android studio not launching application on device

Tags: android, android-studio

my problem is simple the Android studio is not launching the application.

Earlier today, I had an error which required me to change my gradle-wrapper.properties to `"distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip"`
and in build.gradle to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-rc3'`.

After that the Android studio is not launching the application on my device at all. I have tried to restart the pc, Android Studio, and the device(even used different device). In the logcat there is nothing like building...etc. I tried also to clean\ Rebuild

I have checked in the Run/Debug that I have module `app`, and I have tried to create another one also.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: You can use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0` for a start, no need to stay on the rc3. Did you upgrade to Android Studio 2.0 before updating these files ? Do you have a diff of the changes that were made during the upgrade ?

Comment: I had `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'`, i didn't see the difference between the 2 versions

Comment: @Philippe  I am working on Android Studio 2.0 Preview 2. I tried to change now to grade:`1.5.0` and it launched but still refuse to launch on `2.0.0`. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea. Try to create a new project from scratch with Android Studio 2.0 and see if any of the config files are different. Or look up a project on GitHub for example.